# JSONArray not properly working with gwt-test-utils

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-test-utils

The following code

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArrayMixed;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONArray;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONString;

[...]

JsArrayMixed jsArray = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
jsArray.push("something");    
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsArray);    
System.out.println(jsonArray.size());
```

will print "0" instead of the expected "1" when run with gwt-test-utils. Looking at the `JSONArrayPatcher` in gwt-test-utils it seems that the value given to the constructor is completely ignored.

Is there a way to make those lines print "1"? Maybe there is a way to patch the constructor of `JSONArray`?

Answer (score 0):

`JSONArray` has nothing to do with `JsArrayMixed`. `JSONArray` is `org.json.JSONArray` and `JsArrayMixed` is gwt client object of type `com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArrayMixed`. These are so completedly from different class hierarchy, that they don't just understand each other.

`JSONArray` maybe works if you construct it with `JSONObject` instance or another `JSONArray`.

You have to invent another way to construct your mixed object.

---

**My sources:**

[1] http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html 
[2] http://srcrr.com/java/google/gwt/2.2/reference/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsArrayMixed.html

Comment: Maybe these both know what JSON is and both handle data from JSON, but well, other option can be binary and every binary objects do not all understand each others, neither.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am using  `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONArray` not `org.json.JSONArray`. I edited my question to clarify that.